# Why MongoDB Date range query returning emtpy result when querying for same date and one day before?

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am having a mongodb collection which stores payments info of users who bought videos

This is the content :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea17279ca73ec19f84ac39a"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-04-23T10:48:25.920Z"), // 23 Apr 2020
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-04-23T10:48:25.920Z"),
    "accountId" : "0000",
    "postId" : ObjectId("5e8da8533efaa66ce53bd3bb"),
    "paidBy" : ObjectId("5e92e9ffda29d826d46f7562"),
    "paidGet" : ObjectId("5e465194366a412b7107a1c8"),
    "chargeId" : "0520114401000000538",
    "status" : "Charging",
    "isDeleted" : false,
    "chargeAmount" : "12",
    "transferAmount" : "0",
    "postPrice" : "1.00",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea173a9ca73ec19f84ac39c"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-04-23T10:53:29.957Z"), //23 Apr 2020
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-04-23T10:53:29.957Z"),
    "accountId" : "0000",
    "postId" : ObjectId("5e8da8533efaa66ce53bd3bb"),
    "paidBy" : ObjectId("5ea1673bca73ec19f84ac392"),
    "paidGet" : ObjectId("5e465194366a412b7107a1c8"),
    "chargeId" : "0520114401000000552",
    "status" : "Charging",
    "isDeleted" : false,
    "chargeAmount" : "12",
    "transferAmount" : "0",
    "postPrice" : "1.00",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

My Issue :

I need to query the collection based on date range against the field `createdAt` :

I am using `$gte` and `$lte` for querying

Now I need to find payments happened on 23 Apr 2020

My Queries are :

```
db.payment.find({"createdAt" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2020-04-22") , "$lte" : ISODate("2020-04-23")}}).pretty()

db.payment.find({"createdAt" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2020-04-23") , "$lte" : ISODate("2020-04-23")}}).pretty()
```

But this query not returning anything : That is , Date ranges **22 Apr 20 - 23 Apr 20 && 23 Apr 20 - 23 Apr 20** , returning empty result

But this query working that is if I add extra one day that is apr 24 [22 Apr 20 - 24 Apr 20]

```
db.payment.find({"createdAt" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2020-04-22") , "$lte" : ISODate("2020-04-24")}}).pretty()
```

And also this : [23 Apr 20 - 24 Apr 20]

```
db.payment.find({"createdAt" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2020-04-23") , "$lte" : ISODate("2020-04-24")}}).pretty()
```

---

Date D => date to be find = 23 Apr 2020:

So my issue is , if I gave a date range that starts one day before of that Date D and ends on same date D [22 Apr 20 - 23 Apr 20] ... No result :

And If I gave same date D in start and end ,[23 Apr 20 - 23 Apr 20]...  no result returned

But if I gave one day extra in end date , result coming [22 Apr 20 - 24 Apr 20]

And also if the start date is Date D and end date is one day extra , result is coming : [23 Apr 20 - 24 Apr 20]

---

Why this weird  matching ? Please help me

Comment: that's because when you specify date like `ISODate("2020-04-23")`, it means `2020-04-23 00:00:00` and hence it will include records for that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you observe it carefully `ISODate("2020-04-23T10:48:25.920Z")`, you would notice that it got created on `2020-04-23` at `10:48:25.920`. So when you do `ISODate("2020-04-23")` it would result in `ISODate("2020-04-23T00:00:00.000Z")` that's the reason why you're not getting any results back. So your initial two queries which are failing has to be like this :

```
db.payment.find({"createdAt" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2020-04-22") , "$lt" : ISODate("2020-04-24")}}).pretty()

db.payment.find({"createdAt" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2020-04-23") , "$lt" : ISODate("2020-04-24")}}).pretty()
```

So when you do `"$lt" : ISODate("2020-04-24")` it would ensure that none of the documents from `"2020-04-24"` will be pulled out in result cause we're checking for `createdAt < ISODate("2020-04-24T00:00:00.000Z")`.

Comment: Actually , the flow is , in the web site , the user select the date range 22 apr - 23 apr , nothing comes

Comment: So How I have to change my query ?

Comment: this format working :: db.payment.find({"createdAt" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2020-04-22T00:00:00.000Z") , "$lte" : ISODate("2020-04-23T23:59:59.999Z")}}).pretty()

Comment: @LordCommander : when user selects 22 - 23 as I’ve given like above you need to search between 22 - 24 your api code has to handle this prior to hitting db with a query. So you need frame as ‘>22 00:00 - < 24 00:00’ or ‘>22 00:00 - < 23 23:59’ on find’s like this, you’ll have better options with aggregation but I would not opt aggregation for this small thing which can be easily handled by code + mongo find()..

Comment: @LordCommander ohh you already commented I’ve not noticed yes correct thats what you need to do which is easy to get either 24 or ‘23 23:59’